# Python script for parsing and using CSV data

Tags: python, csv

I am given a CSV file of stations, with data like this:

```
station_id,date,temperature_c
68,2000.375,10.500
68,2000.542,5.400
68,2000.958,23.000
68,2001.125,20.400
68,2001.292,13.300
68,2001.375,10.400
68,2001.958,21.800
68,2002.208,15.500
```

and so on for many different `station_id`s.

Then I want to create a Python program that (1) gives the minimum reading (the third column) and (2) the station with the maximum "travel distance" with its readings. Thus if a station has 3 readings of -5,0,8 then that would mean a travel distance of 13. This can take an optional date range. Here is what I did.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import random
import sys

# In order to track each station's statistics, we'll create a Station class
# to hold the data on a per-station basis.
class Station:

  def __init__(self):
    self.readings = []
    self.minimum = 99999999.0
    self.travel = 0

  # travel holds the change in temperature reading-by-reading
  def get_travel(self):
    return self.travel

  def set_travel(self, n):
    self.travel += abs(n)

  # getter & setter for station minimums
  def get_minimum(self):
    return self.minimum

  def set_minimum(self, n):
    self.minimum = n

  # infrastructure for future code expansion
  def get_readings(self):
    return self.readings

  def set_readings(self, date, temp):
    self.readings.append({ "date" : date, "temp" : temp})

"""
Reporter class handles a list of Stations
"""
class Reporter:

  def __init__(self):
    # stations dict with entries for holding the specified stats.
    self.stations = defaultdict(Station)
    self.global_minimum = { "station" : "default", "date" : 1, "temp" : 9999999 }
    self.longest_travel = { "station" : "default", "range" : 0 }

  """
  Determines which station recorded the coldest temperature
  args: CSV file
  returns: dict with data
  """
  def minimum_temperature(self, filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as datafile:
      try:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(datafile)
        next(csv_reader)

        # reading line-by-line since CSV could be a big file
        for row in csv_reader:
          station, date, temp = row

          # save the station's readings
          self.stations[station].set_readings(date, temp)

          temp = float(temp)

          if (temp < self.stations[station].get_minimum()):
            self.stations[station].set_minimum(temp)

          if(temp < self.global_minimum["temp"]):
            self.global_minimum = { "station" : station, "temp" : temp, "date" : date }

          # The specs state that in the event that a tie occurs simply return
          # one pair at random.
          if (temp == self.global_minimum["temp"]):
            if (random.randint(1,100) % 2 == 0):
              self.global_minimum = { "station" : station, "date" : date, "temp" : temp }

      except csv.Error as e:
        sys.exit('file {}, line {}: {}'.format(filename, reader.line_num, e))

    return self.global_minimum

  """
  Determines which station "traveled" the most
  args: CSV file, begin date (optional), end date (optional)
  returns: dict with data
  """
  def max_travel(self,filename,begin=1.0,end=9999.9):
    with open(filename, 'r') as datafile:

      try:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(datafile)
        next(csv_reader)

        # reading line-by-line since CSV could be a big file
        for row in csv_reader:

          station, date, temp = row
          # save for future expansion
          self.stations[station].set_readings(date, temp)

          date = float(date)

          if date > begin and date < end:

            temp = float(temp)

            self.stations[station].set_travel(temp)
            travel = self.stations[station].get_travel()

            if ( travel > self.longest_travel["range"]):
              self.longest_travel = { "station" : station, "range" : travel }

      except csv.Error as e:
        sys.exit('file {}, line {}: {}'.format(filename, reader.line_num, e))

    return self.longest_travel


if __name__ == "__main__":

  csv_file = sys.argv[1]

  # fetch lowest temperature
  reporter = Reporter()
  global_minimum = reporter.minimum_temperature(csv_file)
  print("station {} had the global minimum on {}".format(global_minimum["station"], global_minimum["date"]))

  # fetch maximum travel overall
  longest_travel = reporter.max_travel(csv_file)
  print("station {} had the greatest travel at {}".format(longest_travel["station"], longest_travel["range"]))

  # now try a date range
  reporter2 = Reporter()
  begin = 2001.0
  end = 2006.0
  longest_travel = reporter2.max_travel(csv_file,begin,end)
  print("for {} to {}, station {} had the greatest travel at {}".format(begin, end, longest_travel["station"], longest_travel["range"]))
```

I'm particularly interested in speeding it up and memory usage but also how to Pythonically deal with with getters/setters.

Answer (score 1):

## Getters and Setters

If you are to use this pattern, the `@property` decorator will accomplish this in a more pythonic way:

```py
class Station:
    def __init__(self):
        self.readings = []
        self._minimum = 99999999.0
        self._travel = 0


    @property
    def minimum(self, value):
        return self._minimum


    @minimum.setter
    def minimum(self, value):
        self._minimum = value


    @property
    def travel(self, value):
        return self._travel


    @travel.setter
    def travel(self, value):
        self._travel = abs(value)


    def add_reading(self, date, temp):
        self.readings.append({ "date" : date, "temp" : temp})


# access the elements this way
station = Station()
print(station.travel)
0

station.travel += 1
print(station.travel)
1
```

However, the setter pattern doesn't really make sense for your `readings`, because you aren't really setting, you're appending. So keep a function that appends a reading to the readings list, it's more explicit this way. I wouldn't expect:

```py
station.readings = ('date', 'reading')
```

to do anything other than set the attribute, but it actually has a surprising side-effect.

## Spacing

Your indentation should be four spaces, not two.

Answer (score 0):

- Probably a typo in your `except` clauses; I suspect it's supposed to say `csv_reader.line_num`.
- What is going on with the "travel"? What you've actually written is "sum of absolute values", but I assume what you actually want is *either* "max minus min" *or* "sum of day-to-day deltas".
- My opinion is that getters/setters/properties are inherently un-pythonic. More importantly, they're *opaque*. They look like attributes but they're functions that can have side-effects. Don't hide the possibility of side-effects from the audience; *do* just use an actual attribute wwh
- I like the `DictReader` provided by the `csv` module. It's not *everything* we might ask for, but it'll save us accidentally handling malformed data.
- You're doing a lot of work to handle the file in a stream, but you're also reading the file multiple times and you're keeping all the data in memory once it's read.

  - This could get buggy. For example, in your `main`, you re-use `reporter` for the second pass, which means it will contain every datapoint *in duplicate*.
  - You should pick one: Either get everything you want in a single pass, or read all the data into an appropriate structure and run queries on that. Since you specify speed and memory usage as concerns, I'll assume you want the first choice (but I suspect that's the wrong decision).
- You probably don't need a `Reporter` class at all. It's not helping you manage any state (that you want to keep) across functions, so just declare your functions in the top namespace.